# I cannot remove entity class from symfony project without mistakes

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have the project with symfony5 and doctrine orm. I created entity in my project. And now I want to delete the entity from model. I deleted relashionships this entity and made migration. Then i deleted this entities from the project and made migration. But when I try to create new entity in php bin/console, i get next error:

```
 Warning: include(C:\OpenServer\elearning\vendor\composer/../../src/Entity/Theme.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What am i doing wrong?

I tried to make php bin/console d:s:u --force, but the error still appears

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but i just had the same problem.

Try running `composer dump-autoload` to generate a new classmap.
 Your `...\Entity\Theme.php` probably still exists there.

After that, you should be able to run console commands again.